# Laravel Excel Parent/Child Classes

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the following package called Laravel-Excel for my Laravel application. Link provided below.

What I would like to be able to do is create a parent class that will generate all my reports and I can have child classes where I define column headings and the data needed to create the Excel document. I looked around to see if anyone has accomplished this. I have not found this to be the case. Any suggestions on what I have so far?

```
<?php

namespace App\Reports;

use Excel;

class Report 
{
    protected $columnHeadings = [];

    protected $dataSet;

    public function generate()
    {
        Excel::create($filename, function ($excel) {
            $excel->sheet($sheetname, function ($sheet) {
                $sheet->appendRow($this->columnHeadings, null, 'A1', false, false);
                $dataSet->each(function($data) use ($sheet) {

                });
            });
        })->download($type);
    }
}
```

http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve it's called [`template pattern design`](https://www.sitepoint.com/overriding-strategy-logic-the-template-method-pattern/). Where you can have a base class that often its not incialized it kind of serves as a resolver, so most of the time you would want an abstract class as a base class.

In that base class you can define some properties in your case `filename` and `columns`, which will be overridden from the child class. The class structure you may want its:

> ```
> Base Abstract ReportGenerator 
>
>  ->Child MonthlyReport Class 
>
>  ->Child YearlyReport Class
> ```

Code in your case:

```
<?php

namespace App\Reports;

use Excel;

abstract class ReportGenerator
{
    protected $columnHeadings = [];

    protected $dataSet;

    protected $fileName;

    public function generate()
    {
        return Excel::create($this->filename, function ($excel) {
            $excel->sheet($sheetname, function ($sheet)use ($headings = $this->columnHeadings) {
                $sheet->appendRow($headings, null, 'A1', false, false);
                $dataSet->each(function($data) use ($sheet) {

                })->download($type);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your child class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Reports;

use App\Reports\ReportGenerator;
 

class MonthlyReport extends ReportGenerator {

        //set the properties for this specific class so they can override the base properties whenever this class its init.

      protected $columnHeadings = [];
    
      protected $dataSet;

      protected $fileName ='Monthly Report';

      public function __construct(SomeModel $model){
          
           //set the required headings for this specific report
           $this->columnHeadings = ['some headings']; 
           $this->data = $model;
          
      }

      public function generateMonthlyReport(){
       
         return $this->generate();
      }
 
}
```

So whenever you want to generate a monthly report you might do:

`MonthlyReport->generate($someModel);` and you can create other classes to generate different reports but extending abstract claass!